# Communication between android application with Kernel

Tags: android, kernel

I need to communication between an Android application and a separate kernel module present on the device.

I got some methods like **Shared memory** but wanted to know if there are any other methods.
The data to be exchanged is only text and frequent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ioctl or open fd on the device created by kernel module.